# How to trigger daily APEX atuomated processes, using Batch or Queueable?

Tags: apex

I want to create a automated process in APEX that would run daily.  My job look like this:

```
global without sharing class TriggerBot {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Trigger Bot' description='Trigger Bot')
    global static void TriggerBot(List<TriggerBotParameters> params) {
        System.debug('Trigger Bot Started');
    }
}
```

I wrote a scheduler to trigger my job, which check the correct day of week in the database entry:

```
global class BotScheduler implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        Date d = System.today();
        Datetime dt = (DateTime)d;
        String dayOfWeek = dt.format('EEEE');
        
        // Run all bots on the same day of week
        List<Setting__c> configs = 
            [SELECT Id FROM Setting__c WHERE Schedule_Day_of_Week__c = :dayOfWeek];
        
        for(Integer i =0; i<configs.size(); i++){
            Setting__c curSetting = configs[i];
            TriggerBotParameters triggerParam = new TriggerBotParameters();
            triggerParam.ConfigurationId = curSetting.Id;
            // how to trigger the job from here?
        }
    }
}
```

I am stuck on how to actually trigger the process job from the scheduler?  Should I use a queueable job or use a batch?  And how do I set it up?

Comment: You should never use the `global` access modifier. As for the actual scheduling, if you just need to schedule daily then do it through the UI.

Comment: Sure but how do I trigger my APEX class from the scheduler job?

Comment: You shouldn't launch invocable classes directly from async apex, the invocable should be used by Flows or Process Builders and then delegate work to a queueable or batchable; the schedulable can also delegate to the same queueable or batchable